# What skills and education are required for HFT?

Tags: high-frequency

I'm a university student and I'm quite interested in High Frequency Trading Algorithms. What courses should I take and what skills should I acquire so that I can work in this field?

So far, I've been developing web applications and Android apps as a software engineer.

Comment: You'll have more luck with this type of questions at [quantnet](http://www.quantnet.com/).